# Dynamic CSS is not being cached by browsers - response returns 200 OK instead of 304 Not Modified

Tags: php, css, caching

I have dynamic CSS file like this:

```
$Css = get_from($_u_6);



/* do stuff and other things here... */



$expires = 60*60*24; 
header("Pragma: public");
header("Cache-Control: maxage=".$expires.", must-revalidate, public");
header('Expires: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time()+$expires) . ' GMT');
header('Content-type: text/css');


echo $Css;
```

Headers are set correctly:
    https://i.stack.imgur.com/8nF48.png

But  The server always responds with **HTTP 200 OK** (and the correct content), rather than with a **HTTP 304 ( Not Modified)**.

How can I convince the browser and the server to cache these dynamic css files and to send 304 response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Expires:` header tells the browser or cache server how long it can keep reusing the same resource without reloading it from the origin server.

If you want the browser to make a conditional request (eg. using `If-Modified-Since:` or `If-None-Match:`), you need to send a `Last-Modified:` and/or `ETag:` header, **and** you need to write code to test for these headers and produce the appropriate response (`304` or `200`).

See <del>[RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616)</del> [RFC 7232](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232) for full details.

Comment: RFC2616 has now been obsoleted by [RFC 7230](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230), [RFC 7231](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231), [RFC 7232](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7232), [RFC 7233](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7233), [RFC 7234](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7234) and [RFC 7235](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7235).